# Zero Morphisms in a Category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

**STATEMENT:** This is taken from Robert Ash's,Basic Abstract Algebra.
Let us call $0$ the zero object in an arbitrary category.  And let us denote $0_{AB}$ the zero morphism from  an object $A$ in the category to an object $B$ in the same category.  Why is it that given any arbitrary morphism, $h$, in this category that $h0_{AB}=0_{AB}h=0_{AB}$.

EXACT QUOTE FROM BOOK: "Note that since a zero morphism goes through a zero object, it follows that for  an arbitrary morphism $h$, we have $h0=0h=0$."

**QUESTION:** I don't get how the last relationship with the morphism $h$ is derived. I am assuming that he assumes $A=B$ otherwise the thing he states can't necessarily hold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *zero object* $0$ in a category is an object that is both *initial* and *terminal*. Initial means there exists a unique morphism from this object to any other given object $A$, call it $0_{0A}: 0 \rightarrow A$. Terminal means there exists a unique morphism from any given object $A$ to this object, call it $0_{A0}: A \rightarrow 0$.

If our category contains a zero object $0$, given any two other objects $A$ and $B$ we can define the zero morphism $0_{AB}$ to be $A \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow B$, where the arrows are the unique morphisms. That is, $0_{AB} = 0_{0B} \circ 0_{A0}$.

Now what if you have an arbitrary morphism $h: B \rightarrow C$? *Claim*: $h \circ 0_{AB} = 0_{AC}$. *Proof*: $h \circ 0_{AB} = h \circ 0_{0B} \circ 0_{A0}$. The morphism $h \circ 0_{0B}: 0 \rightarrow C$ must equal $0_{0C}$ by uniqueness (i.e. because $0$ is an initial object). Then $h \circ 0_{AB} = 0_{0C} \circ 0_{A0} = 0_{AC}$.

Now suppose $h: C \rightarrow A$. *Claim*: $0_{AB} \circ h = 0_{CA}$. Prove this one yourself (the proof is very similar to the above paragraph).

Comment: What troubles me was just his notation. Why does $0_{AC}=0_{CA}$. Don't they belong to different morphism sets, hence not equal unless A=C?

Comment: There's some abuse of notation going on here. $0_{AC} \neq 0_{CA}$ unless $A = C$. If the book actually had $h0_{AB} = 0_{AB}h = 0_{AB}$, then he must mean $h \in \mathrm{Mor}(B,B)$ the first time it shows up, and then separately $h \in \mathrm{Mor}(A,A)$ the second time it shows up. It would be fine, though an abuse, to write $h0 = 0h = 0$, where $0$ is understood to be the zero map from whatever its head happens to be to whatever its tail happens to be. (Each of these being in a different morphism set potentially.)

Comment: Alright thanks. That clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

$h0=0$ because the zero object is initial, $0h=0$ because the zero object is terminal.